# Edit text drawn with DrawText() - C++ Win32/API

Tags: c++, winapi, netbeans

I have this code in my project to draw some text on a screen:

```
DrawText(hDC, "Sample String", -1, rect, DT_WORDBREAK);
```

How would I go about editing text already drawn to the screen with this function? I would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!
Oh, and my IDE is Netbeans 7.0.1 (:

Comment: DrawText is a very low-level API: you give it text, it turns it into pixels on the screen; there's nothing there to edit, just pixels. Your best bet is to find an Edit Control or Text Box control, and let it do the work for you. Behind the scenes, these controls draw and redraw themselves with every keystroke (often using DrawText or similar to do the actual rendering) to keep the displayed text current - and they take care of things like backspacing, scrolling, multi-line input, and so on. In pure Win32, creating an EDIT window is the way to go here.

Comment: @BrendanMcK - Would a Text Control do the same trick?

Comment: @BradleyNeilReed; sounds like it should. The exact name of a control tends to vary somewhat with the framework you're using; so for plain Win32, it's a control called "EDIT", in MFC it's a CEdit class, in Java AWT it's TextField, in .Net (eg. C#) it's System.Windows.Forms.TextBox - and so on. Perhaps the thing to do is to figure out what UI framework you are using (not just the language), and then check the documentation for that framework for a simple example that should help get you started. I'd advise using Win32 API directly only as a last resort since it requires a lot more effort to use.

Comment: @BrendanMcK - Yes. I'm using plain Win32. But that's because I'm a beginner and am just learning the foundations first. Maybe I'll use MFC in the future, but for now I'll stick with the Win32 API. But thanks, I tried it and got it working with a static control. (: